# How do I calculate the equivalent resistance of this kind of circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance

If I want to calculate the resistance between \$a\$ and \$b\$, that is,  \$R_{ab}\$. How do I calculate the equivalent resistance of this kind of circuit? All resistors are \$22Ω\$

[image]

I know we we ignore the resistors between two point, take a and b for example, if we want to calculate the equivalent resistance between \$a\$ point and \$b\$ point, but in here, I am not sure about which resistors should I ignore first, R1~R5 resistor?

The answer is \$R_{ab}=10Ω\$, but I don't know how to calculate it! Can anyone teach me how to calculate the resistor between \$a\$ and \$b\$, that is, \$R_{ab}\$?

Answer (score 4):

As (nearly) always, try and simplify: -

Move from top left to top right by using two [star to delta transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) to produce: -

- Ra, Rb, Rc

and

- Rd, Re, Rf

[image]

Bottom picture is the simplified combination of the the above right.

Can you take it from here by doing another star to delta transform on 3 more resistors?

Comment: @shineele - are we done with this one now?

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution would be to change the deltas to stars.
So use the Star-Delta conversion. and after you should simplify it.

[something like this](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-6095e4920341eb17d288bbedcd90ed56-c)

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative much easier way, compared to star-delta, to solve for the resistors. (By the way, your answer is incorrect, the equivalent resistance is \$16\Omega.\$)
Since all the resistors are same symmetry arguments can be applied. By symmetry, the current going in branch \$ae\$ is expected to be same as in \$eb\$. Similarly, current in \$ac\$ is same as current going in \$db\$. This is shown in the figure below. This also implies the current in \$ao\$ is same as in \$ob\$. Moreover, the current through \$co\$ has to equal that through \$od\$.

[image]

Clearly, no current flows through \$eo\$ and from \$ao\$ to \$oc\$ or \$od\$. You can thus remove the resistor R3 and the connection at node o as shown below, where the 'x' means the connection is removed:
[image]

Assuming all resistors are equal to R, there are now three parallel branches with resistor values: \$2R, 2R\$, \$2R+\frac{2R}{3} = \frac{8R}{3}\$ 
$$R_{eq} = \frac{R.\frac{8R}{3}}{R+\frac{8R}{3}} = \frac{8R}{11} = 16\Omega$$

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to homework problems. We expect the OP to do a significant amount of work themselves, and try to just give them hints so they learn how to solve problems on their own.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson He already knew the answer. Clearly, he was stuck. Anyways, it is a question and answer site and I don't care if OP is doing work himself or not. Also the question is not tagged as homework so I don't know how you concluded it is a homework. I just wanted to show him another approach which is less computationally intensive.